# When Excel loads, move view window to specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel worksheet with has a calendar. However, this calendar start from the beginning of the year. I am trying to set up a VBA script so that when the excel loads, it jumps to the column with holds today's day.

I have go it to the point when I find the column as a numerical value, but cannot seem to get it to move to that column.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim Today As Date: Today = Date
Dim VarianceDate As String: VarianceDate = Today
Dim TargetCell As Range, TargetCol As Integer

Set TargetCell = Rows("2").Find(What:=CDate(VarianceDate), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not TargetCell Is Nothing Then TargetCol = TargetCell.Column

Debug.Print TargetCol

End Sub
```

This will print out 165.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Select `TargetCell.Select`